# angular - access element by dynamic id from html

Tags: angularjs, dom

http://plnkr.co/edit/BeBKU48YGSJaYPNoaBGF?p=preview

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="" ng-init="names=['1','2','3']">
    <div ng-repeat="x in names">
      <button ng-click="getElementById(x).innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>

      <p id="{{x}}"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason I cant access the ID. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use an `ngClick` function and assign the Date that way? (Way way way cleaner than an inline onclick native JS function blended in a repeat)

Comment: The `ngClick` is a function that is supposed to be called in the controller.

Comment: I read that dom manipulation should not be in the controller. Anyway it still not working. http://plnkr.co/edit/BeBKU48YGSJaYPNoaBGF?p=preview. if you can fix the code it will be good.

Comment: You are going to want to create a directive to handle what you are trying to achieve, i.e. modifying the dom. Moving the logic to the view, bypassing the controller, is still against the spirit of angular.

Comment: Can somebody please tell me why the code above doesnt work befor we moving to directives and controllers with a fail code?

Comment: You have to many errors here to make it work, here is working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/za0ZhAmUR5ZyOzNfeNLc?p=preview

Comment: im not trying to do that with x.date. Im trying In that way so I can learn how  to access element by dynamic id from html. Any help will be greate.